# Flexicioius selectionMode="singleRow" allowing multi-select

Tags: apache-flex, flexicious

I have a `FlexDataGrid` with `selectionMode="singleRow"`. In that grid, I have a `FlexDataGridCheckBoxColumn` with `radiobuttonmode="true"`.

However, if you click 'quickly' on two of the radiobuttons in the grid above, you can actually select multiple rows. This is obviously undesirable, and I am wondering if this is a bug or perhaps I have done something incorrectly.

Comment: You may be best suited contacting flexicious support

Answer (score 0):

This happens because we have a timer listening that prevents two fast clicks dispatching two clicks and a double click, there by unselecting the row you intended to double click on. If you do not need double click functionality, you can just set enableDoubleClickTimer=false. If you need double click functionality, adjust the double click timer interval (itemClickTimerDuration) - that is defaulted to 250 msec.